# How to adjust rank for ad for its recent trend in click-through-rate?

Tags: time-series, ranking, trend

I am building an optimization service for an Adtech company. For ranking ads in terms of performance, I am using formula: Log(impressions)*eCPM. Impressions means the number of times ad was served/shown. eCPM = estimated Cost/Revenue per 1000 impressions. The problem with this metric is the cumulative effect of eCPM allows the ad to achieve higher rank after ad has been served for quite a some time. This is because ad had performed well earlier but hasn't been performing now, hence, eCPM remain high inspite for recent drop in performance. I would like to introduce recent trend of ctr or eCPM in the formula. Any recommendations?

One such recommendation is: Log(impressions)*eCPM*(d(eCPM)/dt) where dt is around 1 hour